# How to Estimate the Noise of an Image / Estimation of the Noise in an Image?

Tags: noise, image-processing, estimation

I want to know how to estimate the noise of an image?

Also is this represent the camera's noise?

Does anyone know how to estimate the noise of an image or camera?

## Update:

Especially, I want to know about the A, B, C from as following.
How Can I plot these A, B,C curve?
Also I want to know what is C. What does C mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various methods to estimate the noise of a signal (or adapt a threshold to be used later in PCA for example).

There are adaptive methods and statistical methods. Statistical methods employ a statistical model of the noise and estimate from the data, while adaptive methods iteratively filter the data until a certain threshold of (reduced signal) accuracy is reached. These are just generalities of the most used approaches.

The following references deal (mostly) with images from cameras:

1. [Noise Estimation from a Single Image](http://msr-waypoint.com/pubs/75593/Liu-CVPR06.pdf)
2. [Automatic Estimation and Removal of Noise from a Single Image](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/larryz/04359321.pdf)
3. [A noise-estimation algorithm for highly non-stationary environments](http://ecs.utdallas.edu/loizou/speech/noise_estim_article_feb2006.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for letting me But especially, If you can would please let me know how to plot like above A,B,C?

Comment: @gmotree, where do these plots come from? i suspect these use some algorithm to draw these data. So use the same algorithm. There is not one fixed algorithm for this problem, but various approaches as explained in the answer some work better for some data while worse for other data'.

Comment: that plot come from your references

Comment: @gmotree, oh ok,, then use this algorithm. i'm not sure if these are open-source somewhere, if not implement the algorithm yourself (in matlab or scilab for example)

Comment: Thanks. But if I can got a algorithm from the references, I did not ask to here.

Comment: @gmotree, sorry i dont understand, the answer answered your (original) question, then the references detail the algorithms. i suggest you use a signal processing tool like scilab or matlab to make any test implementation for your use-case

Comment: sorry, your answer is very general answer. I want to concrete answer not general answer.

Comment: @gmotree, the plots are the Camera response function (model) and the estimated noise deviation (from [this reference](http://msr-waypoint.com/pubs/75593/Liu-CVPR06.pdf)). The details and further references are there plus a small explanation of how the methods work. In these sites one will not make the work for you. These are Q&A sites to help understanbding and development not implement your project. try another site

Comment: Sorry But I don't want to somebody works for me instead. I need to concrete hint for solving the problems.

Comment: @gmotree to avoid discouraging you, maybe another answer will appear which is closer to what you need after latest edit. **But** i say again that these methods require some code and skill and is not just one-line functions to call and solve the problem, so i would not expect an answer to provide with source code

Comment: Actually I'm waiting someone who has really works for this. also I can get some concrete hint not just works for me..Thanks for  interesting this subject, anyway.

Comment: @gmotree, what concrete hints do you need? do you work in matlab or python? it is not specified? Do you know how to compute standard deviation of a signal? Do you know how to fit data to a model? These are not specified, how do you expect someone to provide "concrete hints". try editing your question to be for specific hints

Comment: I just trying to tell you about this question is not asking to someone work for me. whatever specified or not. I just want to spend time to solve my problem. why don't you concentrate focus this subject?

Comment: @gmotree, if you cant be specific about the hints you need, how do you expect an answer. i said before these methods require code and skills there is not a command you type in your PC to solve these problems, excerpt if you use a commercial or freeware image processing software which happens to implement these things. Try to be mote specific of what you need by "concrete hints", which environment or language do you use to implement this problem? Do you understand the basics of signal processing? If you edit your question i will try to add more speciifc information. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks M, first question is how to plot A how can I plot the curve. As I know, x axis and y axis are meaning brightness and STD. But the A plot is continuous not dots. so I think this means that are some kind of not the real. I mean that the not the real is meaning the simulation result or something like that. but I can't expression exactly.

Comment: @gmotree, this is not specific question because it is not about a single thing but covers a lot of ground, anyway i will answer. The plot is made-up of discrete points the plot *seems* continous because the dots/points are cconencted but the data are discrete. The plot represents a model of the camera response function which is actually estimated from data. The plot is very easy to make once you have the data (in scilab or matlab it is just a single command)  Any questions so far?

Comment: Oh. that are made of discrete points, I didn't know that. Thanks  I have one query about " The plot represents a model of the camera response function which is actually estimated from data. ". then do that curves made up actually estimated from data? what does difference between A and C? I think C is fitting actually estimated from data.But I assume that  A is purely come  from some kind of equation.

Comment: @gmotree, if i am not mistaken the 3 lower plots are the estimated noise deviation and the actual noise deviation (i will take a closer look, since i read it up very quickly), in any case these methods need some study and hands-on signal-processing basics (like estimating variance from data etc. )

Comment: I think they call the ground truth, the name of the function as NLF(Noise Level Function) Also τ(I) = E[(IN − I)^2],  or τ(I; f, σs, σc) = E[(IN (f −1(I),f, σs, σc) − I)^2]. But I can't get this one how to plot by using this equation. do you have any  ideas?

Comment: Link (2) is dead